# How to access Bokeh's data and trigger events on the front-end from outside?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, bokeh

I'd like to filter and save an embedded Bokeh plot's data dynamically,
preserving the zoom too. It looks like Bokeh is a Backbone project and I am not sure how to access its data and call triggers on it from the outside. Function `components()` does not seem to render inputs for Bokeh and we'd need more functionality anyway.

Where could I look for examples? How would you solve this problem?

Comment: Hi Barnabas, this question and your other question are fairly vague. I can't really envision what you are wanting to do. I'd suggest you come by the Bokeh mailing list (https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/?pli=1#!forum/bokeh) with a much more detailed description of your use-case and some example code of what you've tried. It's hard to have an extended conversation in SO comments and various SO users get very upset if "answers" aren't a specific way.

Comment: @bigreddot Hi, ok, I agree thanks for the invite, I'll come around to your mailing list tomorrow.

Comment: Let meg get back to this in 4-6 hours.

Answer (score 0):

What I figured so far is the following:
CustomJS supplies cb_obj that sometimes has useful data such as selected indices from the drawn points. Combined with ColumnDataSource's source data one can trigger his JS application to pull ajax requests then source.trigger('change') refreshes the plot.
I still don't know how to properly access Bokeh's Backbone data models accross the board.